# Bootstrap align navbar on center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I put brand on center navbar and i want to have navigation to left side and navigation to right side. All this work good but i have question how to align left and right navigation center like on screenshot belowe.[image]

**Here is my code:**

```css
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    height:150px;
}
.brand {
    position: fixed;
    top: 23%;
    left: 50%;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="brand" style="margin: 0; float: none;" href="#">
        <img src="img/profile.png" width="250" />
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Почетна</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">О нама</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Мени</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Прославе</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Галерија</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Локација</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакт</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try doing this to achieve what you wanted.

First remove the class `.mr-auto` on your `<ul class="navbar-nav">` and then add

a class `.custom-css` to `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse custom-css" id="navbarSupportedContent">` since `.navbar-collapse` is already set to `display:flex`, we will now just set the `justify-content: space-around;` to the `.custom-css`

Please see the code below.

```css
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    height:150px;
}
.brand {
    position: fixed;
    top: 23%;
    left: 50%;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
}

.custom-css{
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="brand" style="margin: 0; float: none;" href="#">
        <img src="img/profile.png" width="250" />
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse custom-css" id="navbarSupportedContent">

        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Почетна</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">О нама</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Мени</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Прославе</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Галерија</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Локација</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакт</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ul classes , combine all

elements in one  class and then use Div class Container and then use justify content=centre to bring all elements in center. please see below code.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:150px;
}
.brand {
    position: fixed;
    top: 23%;
    left: 50%;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">



       <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Прославе</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Галерија</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Локација</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакт</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
 Run code snippetReturn to post

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better (and responsive) to make 2 collapsible navs to the left and right of the logo...

https://www.codeply.com/go/8xMhvER5At

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark position-relative">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Почетна</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">О нама</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Мени</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto order-0 mt-lg-5 mt-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
            <a class="mx-auto" href="#">
                <img src="//placehold.it/250" class="rounded-circle">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Прославе</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Галерија</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Локација</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакт</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Then you only need a little CSS for the nav height:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar {
        height:150px;
    }
}
```